# Android - Videoview URL HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-videoview

I have an activity(*activity A*) that can call another activity that load a video from a URL (Videoview). When i come back to the *activity A*, i can go to the activity B where i have a code that execute a request with HttpURLConnection. The problem is that if i go to *activity Video* and load the Videoview, the request in *activity B* return a empty response.

If i change the *activity Video* and delete the Videoview  it work well.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Go4.png)

> Activity Video:

```
    String urlVideo = getIntent().getStringExtra("URL_TRAILER");    
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlVideo);
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);      
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();
```

> HttpURLConnection

```
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response += line;
        }
    } else {
        response = "";

    }
```

Comment: I'm facing this weired issue too...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, use HttpClient and HttpPost instead of HttpURLConnection.

I do not know what is wrong with HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Today: solved using OkHttpClient.